# Ilyama pl2483h giving no signal on digital inputs

Tags: display

I have a Ilyama pl2483h but my hdmi and displayport are not working, when i plug it in it goes from no cable connect to  no signal, but my laptop and pc are both recognizing the monitor in the display preferences also with the brand and model, but it gives no display, i tried resetting the monitor but same result, the vga works fine tho

thanks for helping in advance

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.